# Misplaced line in faq

Tags: bug, site-faq

The bottom of the [notation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/faq#notation) section contains this:

> Please look around to see if your question has been asked before. It’s also OK to ask and answer your own question.

Shouldn't it be [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) or [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask) or [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask)?

<sup>I came across this since I wanted to reuse the section for Chem.SE, of course expanding it for the `\ce{...}` thingy, which lots of people are confused about.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is out of place. It looks like it should be at the end of "What kind of questions can I ask here?", just above the "notation" section. That's the first of the three options you presented.

Comment: Yeah, and actually ideally the whole notation section should probably be further down in the FAQ. But the layout as a whole is decided by the SE team, and they only give us the ability to edit the first two sections.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky: Oh, you can edit it? I thought we'd need some SE magic

Answer (score 2):

Btw, near the *Please look around to see if your question has been asked before* in the FAQ, perhaps there should be a link to a (preferably automatically updated) list of old Physics.SE questions, such that the first question on the list has caused the biggest number of other Physics.SE questions to be closed as duplicates because of it, and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

While we're at it, we can copy [this mathjax tutorial](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-we-use-math-chemistry-formatting-out-here) to meta.Phy, request a mathjax enable, and add a link to it in the notation faq..

Also change the [link in the editor help](http://www.math.harvard.edu/texman/)  to it, the [current one](http://www.math.harvard.edu/texman/) [is too intimidating](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82/tex-tutorial-too-intimidating-extensive)